# How can I avoid Pyinstaller import win32clipboard error?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I use PyInstaller (Win 10) to create a text analyzing app. But though it works fine in Visual Studio Code, the exe file creates an error.

I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile textanalyzer_02.py
```

But starting the exe file gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textanalyzer_02.py", line 2, in <module>
    import win32clipboard
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32clipboard: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
[7604] Failed to execute script textanalyzer_02
```

I tried also:

```
pyinstaller --onefile textanalyzer_02.py --hidden-import win32clipboard
```

But it didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: No-one any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this while having the same issue.  Found a solution that worked for me.  I imported pywintypes into my script before win32clipboard:

```
import pywintypes
import win32clipboard
```

After that, my compiled program ran again without any errors.  Windows 10 / Python 3.8.6 / PyInstaller 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me . I found the two dll files in my python installation folder and simply copied them to \windows\system32

pywintypes39.dll
win32clipboard39.dll

Your file names vill vary with the version of python you have.